# Autocompleting combobox in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox

I'm trying to convert an app that I had previously written in ASP.NET Web Forms to MVC and am stuck on the problem of implementing an autocompleting combobox. Previously, I had used Telerik's RadComboBox, but I'm not sure how to make this work in MVC or if it even can be made to work. Here's the markup code I was using:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="Brand" runat="server" Width="250px" EmptyMessage="Choose a brand" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" OnItemsRequested="Brand_OnItemsRequested" />
```

And the code-behind:

```
protected void Brand_OnItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (BrandCode b in _repository.GetBrandCode(e.Text).OrderBy(b => b.BrandName).Take(10))
  {
    Brand.Items.Add(new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem(b.BrandName, b.BrandCode1));
  }

  Brand.DataBind();
}
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

We do this at work by simply populating a drop down list (or combobox, whichever tickles your fancy), and then using [jquery's autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) by doing something like `$('#myddl').autocomplete();`